# Any good player that could convert MP3 (concatenation of stems) + XML files (lyrics) into karaoke songs (MP4)?

Tags: xml, mp3

AND would render the text formatting that you have within the XML files (text color, font size, swiping colors, etc.) AND on which we could apply a looping background (static or dynamic) - this will be an input from the rendering software.

This would be working like this:

> > mp3 = music file
> >
> > xml = formatted lyrics synchronisation with music (including timing and lyrics)
>
> looping background = input of the karaoke player that could be a static or dynamic image / video.

The player should be able to render these 3 files in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting (if that's an option) the XML into SRT or similar supported format and then hardcode them using Handbrake or similar video editing software. Handbrake is also FOSS.

Comment: Many thanks! And do you think we could reflect the swiping text with this option?

Comment: Colours, position of text are supported by the SRT format. Fonts probably too. If you want more advanced effects I think you'll have to use more advanced software like After Effects or find Karaoke specific software. Even some basic software like Windows Movie Maker has such effects, but it surely won't have the karaoke effects (like when colors change as the text changes). Just as a side note, there's this project called Ultrastar DX, which is a karaoke platform (it's apparently a bit old).